# What is causing Phoenix 1.5.4 to not emit json during this controller test?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So here is the error / stacktrace I am receiving:

```
   ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Jason.Encoder not implemented for {:safe, ["<!DOCTYPE html>\...</html>\n"]} of type Tuple, Jason.Encoder protocol must always be explicitly implemented. This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): Ecto.Association.NotLoaded, Ecto.Schema.Metadata, MixAudit.Advisory, MixAudit.Vulnerability, MixAudit.Report, MixAudit.Dependency, Date, BitString, Jason.Fragment, Any, Map, NaiveDateTime, List, Integer, Time, DateTime, Decimal, Atom, Float
     code: |> post("/api/v1/horses", Jason.encode!(params))
     stacktrace:
       (jason 1.2.1) lib/jason.ex:199: Jason.encode_to_iodata!/2
       (phoenix 1.5.4) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:776: Phoenix.Controller.render_and_send/4
       (phoenix 1.5.4) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:78: Phoenix.Endpoint.RenderErrors.instrument_render_and_send/5
       (phoenix 1.5.4) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:64: Phoenix.Endpoint.RenderErrors.__catch__/5
       (phoenix 1.5.4) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:225: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch/5
       test/my_app_web/controllers/api/v1/horses_controller_test.exs:100: (test)
```

The map params being encoded as json have this shape:

```
params = %{
    "animals" => ["horses"],
    "type" => "mammal",
    "user" => %{
      "id" => "1",
      "email" => "greg@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

The puzzling thing is that "post" refers to a json endpoint - the router pipes through an "api" pipeline which has `plug(:accepts, ["json"])` - other tests in this suite of tests don't seem to have this problem.  I've been doing basic debugging (commenting lines of code out, doing IO.puts, etc) but I still can't seem to isolate where it's failing. Any ideas what might be causing it or if there's a better way to debug? Other controller tests seem to be ok with it, so I'm investigating those, but this issue just doesn't make any sense at the moment.

Comment: this looks like a debug error received when either a runtime error happens or endpoint is not found. Inspect the html received for more information.

Comment: Thanks I ended up figuring it out - it was some weird mocking thing with the way we're using Mox whereby if I didn't provide the proper number of times the mocked function was expected to be called it raised an error.